# nodejs Architecture with multiple sets of data per page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller, callback

**Background Information**

I am making a visual display system using NodeJS and Express that will get information from multiple sources, format them and display them as slides in a full page site on a TV in a reception within my school. I have 5 separate models that follow a similar pattern:

- Connect to source
- Collect data
- Format data into an object
- Return information

**Question**

What is the best way to handle the data from the models coming into the controller? I have 5 different sources, each one will take different amounts of time and I only want to start generating the html for the view once all 5 have returned information as I want to mix the information shown on the slides. Is the best way executing a passed callback function within the model rather than returning the data? If so, is it normal then to have 5 nested callbacks? What happens if one fails, will the entire operation fail?

Ideally what I want is to only execute the rendering function after all 5 sources have returned their information (or errored).

Comment: Just make each of your 5 async operations return a promise that resolves with their result.  Then, pass the 5 promises to `Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]).then(...).catch(...)` and you will know exactly when all 5 are done of if any had an error.

Comment: In the future, questions about code should include the relevant code so we can give a much more specific answer rather than just broad guidance.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00. I actually want broad guidance :)

Comment: This site does not work well for that.  "best way to handle the data from models coming into the controller" could take a whole book to cover all the possibilities because you provide no details at all about what you're really trying to do.  I'd suggest you read [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - all links from the Help Center here.

Comment: As it stands now, your question is too broad and calls primarily for opinion - both of which make it off-topic for the site.